# Nested Headers and Table in Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have several categories and each category has several materials/products. I have a problem since when i decided to delete a material/product on a category, I also delete a material/product in another category? How would able to fix this using reactive forms? How would i independently delete one material only and not another? This is the link to my code [CODE LINK](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qbuzcn?file=app/app.component.ts)

```
patchValues() {
    let rows = this.myForm.get('rows') as FormArray;
    this.orders.forEach(material => {
      material.materials.forEach(x => {
      rows.push(this.fb.group({material_id: x.id,material_name: x.name, quantity: x.qty}))
    })
      })

  }

  onDeleteRow(rowIndex) {
    let rows = this.myForm.get('rows') as FormArray;
    rows.removeAt(rowIndex)
  }
```

Comment: I am not so good with reactive forms man :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the idea is the same,

```
createForm(categories:any,orders:any) //Our form has only an arrayForm "data"
  {
    return this.fb.group(
      {
        //we send orders[0].materials, orders is an array (sorry)
        data:this.fb.array(this.createOrders(categories,orders[0].materials))
      }
    )
  }
  createOrders(categories:any,materials:any) //<--received materials
  {
    //using map, with each "categories" we create a formGroup, so we return a formGroup[]
    return categories.map(x=>
    {
      return this.fb.group({  
        name: x.name,
        materials:this.fb.array(this.createMaterial(materials)) //<--call a function

      })
    })
  }
```

Comment: Can you help me debug it? Thank you. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-enjanf?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: @Josep, I updated my answer. The change is that orders is an array (sorry) The materials was in order[0].materials, is this what I pass to "createdOrders"

Comment: @Joseph, I've was out some days, I response in your question

Answer (score 1):

You need create an array of array. it's easy lose yourself if you haven't careful, but it's some like:

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { 
    this.myForm=this.createForm(this.orders);  //I like pass the argument
  }

  createForm(orders:any) //Our form has only an arrayForm "data"
  {
    return this.fb.group(
      {
        data:this.fb.array(this.createOrders(orders))
      }
    )
  }
  createOrders(orders:any)
  {
    //using map, with each "order" we create a formGroup, so we return a formGroup[]
    return orders.map(x=>
    {
      return this.fb.group({  
        id: x.id,
        name: x.name,
        address: x.adress,
        materials:this.fb.array(this.createMaterial(x.materials)) //<--call a function

      })
    })
  }
  createMaterial(materials:any)  //like the above function return a fromGroup[]
  {
    return materials.map(x=>{
      return this.fb.group({material_id: x.id,material_name: x.name, quantity: x.qty})
    })
  }
```

the template it's like

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onCreateProduct()" >
      <div class="card" formArrayName="data">
        <div class="card-block" 
          *ngFor="let category of myForm.get('data').controls;let i=index">
 <!--see that to show the name of categorie we are using the array categories
     this are not included in the myForm, it's the "variable" categories-->
        CATEGORY:   {{ categories[i].name }}  
        <br>
          <table class="table" [formGroupName]="i" >
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Material ID</th>
                <th>Material Name</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Action</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody formArrayName="materials">
              <tr *ngFor="let row of category.get('materials').controls; let j = index" [formGroupName]="j">
                <td>{{row.value.material_id}}</td>
                <td>{{row.value.material_name}}</td>
                <td>{{row.value.quantity}}</td>
                <td><button type="button" (click)="onDeleteRow(i,j)"> <i class="icofont icofont-ui-delete"></i> Remove</button></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>

          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help. I mean how can iterate the categories? Categories name should be iterated too. It should have two tables. The first table has the header "Woods" and the second has the header "Blocks". Here's the new forked link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-enjanf?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Josep, What do you have? orders, categories or both? What do you want to send (or modify)? I imagined that you have several orders that you want to change (well in your stackbilitz only have one)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion Eliseo. I want to have different categories but each category has same orders