# Is this approach suitable? Using array(s) and class objects to achieve desired output

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I am using Angular 2(?)(typescript/javascript).

My desired output might look something like this:

> 1. Monday
>
>    - | 8:30 to 9:30
>    - | 12:00 to 2:00
>    - | 2:30 to 3:00
> 2. Tuesday
>
>    - | 9:30 to 12:00
> 3. Friday
>
>    - | 1:00 to 5:00

Essentially I am tasked with generating a person's meeting availability, based on their existing calendar entries.

I was intending on looping through an Array of Day objects (dayName, timeslots), timeslots also being an array of various times. I guess this is called using a multidimensional array?

Or am I over thinking this, and the dayName and times can in fact be in the same array?

Comment: I can't tell you if it a suitable approach because you haven't posted any code.

Comment: The first. An array of day objects with a child array of timeslots. It's not techinically a multidimensional array as this would be an array of elements containing further arrays (rather than objects).

Comment: Thanks friend. Do you have any hints on what the code would look like? @net.uk.sweet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jack you want an object like

```
[
 { 
   day:0,
   timeslot:[
     {
       from:8.30,
       to:9.30
     },
     {
       from:12.00,
       to:14.00
     }
     ...
   ]
 { 
   day:1,
   timeslot:[
     {
       from:8.30,
       to:9.30
     },
     {
       from:12.00,
       to:14.00
     }
     ...
   ]
   ...
]
```

About an arrayForm of arrayForm, I write an example in [Nested Headers and Table in Reactive Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48860173/nested-headers-and-table-in-reactive-forms/48868937?noredirect=1#comment84741740_48868937) (the first response)